# iOS Simulator showing only blank screen

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7

I have upgraded few of my macminis to El Capitan 10.11.2 and installed Xcode 7.1. But iOS Simulator is showing some problem. Like, default iOS of Xcode 7.1 is 9.1 and when i launch any device in iOS simulator from SDK 9.1, it just shows me a black screen.

So to check that, i went to Xcode > Preferences and Downloaded SDK 9.0 and 8.4. When i switch to any device from SDK 9.0 or 8.4, they work fine. But i don't know what is going on with its default SDK 9.1.

I tried below of the stuff to troubleshoot the issue.

1. Reinstall Xcode.
2. Reset Device contents.
3. Removed Devices folders and created devices again under SDK 9.1.
4. Deleted and re-created /private/tmp/ with correct permissions.
5. Some more.

None of them worked.

I have pasted some logs of CoreSimulator.log fine when i switch to any device under SDK 9.1.

CoreSimulator.log

```
Jan 10 21:45:21  CoreSimulatorService[331] : Error looking up host support port
Jan 10 21:45:21  CoreSimulatorService[331] : Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=159 "Invalid device state" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid device state}
Jan 10 21:45:21  CoreSimulatorService[331] : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"
Jan 10 21:45:21  CoreSimulatorService[331] : Error looking up host support port
Jan 10 21:45:21  CoreSimulatorService[331] : Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=159 "Invalid device state" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid device state}
Jan 10 21:45:21  CoreSimulatorService[331] : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"
Jan 10 21:45:21  CoreSimulatorService[331] : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"
Jan 10 21:45:21  CoreSimulatorService[331] : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"
Jan 10 21:45:21  CoreSimulatorService[331] : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process"
Jan 10 21:45:21  com.apple.iphonesimulator[447] : Error looking up host support port
Jan 10 21:45:21  com.apple.iphonesimulator[447] : Error looking up host support port
Jan 10 21:45:21  com.apple.iphonesimulator[447] : Error looking up host support port
```

Simulator.log File

```
Jan 10 20:56:58  Simulator[381] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 20:56:58  Simulator[381] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 20:59:39  Simulator[416] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 20:59:39  Simulator[416] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 21:00:21  Simulator[429] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 21:00:21  Simulator[429] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 21:02:45  Simulator[447] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 21:02:45  Simulator[447] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 21:14:06  Simulator[447] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 21:14:06  Simulator[447] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 21:45:21  Simulator[447] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Jan 10 21:45:21  Simulator[447] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
```

Comment: Provide the output of `xcrun simctl list`

Comment: +1 for xcrun simctl list. @Ashish also can you try boot up the simulator (without the app) and then try running your app from XCode.

Comment: Do you remember how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Quit the xcode and kill the pid also and also close and quit the simulator.
Again lunch the xcode and go to window-->divices--> remove all the device and add it agin it will works .